# ThreadPoolExecutor#getPoolSize() vs ThreadPoolExecutor#getActiveCount() what is the difference

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpoolexecutor

I've been playing with `ThreadPoolExecutor`. I needed a method that returns the number of threads which are currently running. So I decided to use `ThreadPoolExecutor#getActiveCount`.

However, when I was testing my methods I noticed something interesting: `ThreadPoolExecutor#getActiveCount` is always equal to `ThreadPoolExecutor#getPoolSize`.

Here is a sample code to reproduce it:

```
class ExecutorTest {

        private ThreadPoolExecutor executor;

        ExecutorTest() {
            executor = (ThreadPoolExecutor) Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
        }

        @Test
        void test() {
            executor.execute(makeRunnable(100, "1"));
            printExecutorState();
            executor.execute(makeRunnable(100, "2"));
            printExecutorState();
            executor.execute(makeRunnable(100, "3"));
            printExecutorState();
            executor.execute(makeRunnable(100, "4"));
            printExecutorState();

            System.out.println("==Changing thread core&max pool size==");
            executor.setCorePoolSize(2);
            executor.setMaximumPoolSize(2);

            printExecutorState();
            assertThat(executor.getMaximumPoolSize()).isEqualTo(2);
            assertThat(executor.getActiveCount()).isEqualTo(4);
        }

        private Runnable makeRunnable(long workTime, String name) {
            return () -> {
                long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                System.out.println("Running " + name);
                while (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime < workTime) {
                }
                System.out.println("Exited " + name);
            };
        }

        private void printExecutorState() {
            int poolSize = executor.getPoolSize();
            int corePoolSize = executor.getCorePoolSize();
            int maxPoolSize = executor.getMaximumPoolSize();
            int running = executor.getActiveCount();

            String currentState = String.format(
                    "poolSize=%d, corePoolSize=%d, maxPoolSize=%d, running=%d",
                    poolSize,
                    corePoolSize,
                    maxPoolSize,
                    running
            );

            System.out.println(currentState);
        }
    }
```

It prints the following:

```
Running 1
poolSize=1, corePoolSize=10, maxPoolSize=10, running=1
Running 2
poolSize=2, corePoolSize=10, maxPoolSize=10, running=2
Running 3
poolSize=3, corePoolSize=10, maxPoolSize=10, running=3
Running 4
poolSize=4, corePoolSize=10, maxPoolSize=10, running=4
==Changing thread core&max pool size==
poolSize=4, corePoolSize=2, maxPoolSize=2, running=4
```

**Now the question is what is the difference between these methods?** Does it make sense to use `ThreadPoolExecutor#getPoolSize` to retrieve number of running threads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the difference if you simply look at javadoc for the functions:

```
/**
* Returns the current number of threads in the pool.
*
* @return the number of threads
*/
public int getPoolSize() 

/**
* Returns the approximate number of threads that are actively
* executing tasks.
*
* @return the number of threads
*/
public int getActiveCount()
```

A thread that is in the pool and not executing any task will be included **getPoolSize()** but not in **getActiveCount()**. In your initial code, you created thread pool with pool size 10, but submitted 4 tasks. Hence pool size was 10 and active count was 4. So use of `ThreadPoolExecutor#getPoolSize` to retrieve number of running threads is **wrong**. It just gives you the number of threads created, the number of actively running threads is given by active count.

In your use case, notice how the pool size is still 4 even after reducing max pool size to 2. So what is happening is 4 threads are executing 4 tasks.

First two threads that complete their task will terminate. At that point, pool size will be reduced to 2 and active will still be 2 (other tasks in progress).

When other two threads complete their task, pool size will remain 2 (core pool size) but active will revert to 0 since no tasks are running.